# DNS queries from Linux failing, Windows succeeding - How to Troubleshoot?

Tags: linux, windows, dns, linux-mint

On a small network, the router is acting as the pass-through DNS server proxy.  When acting as such, DNS queries from Linux are failing, while DNS queries from Windows are succeeding with no delay.

Questions: Ultimately the question is: is there a way to get the Linux DNS queries to work through my router.  Failing that, then what is causing only Linux DNS queries to fail, or if unknown then what are steps I can take to take to troubleshoot further to find out the root failure cause(s).

Network design: 192.168.2.X is the subnet.  Standard cable modem with Netgear R6700v2 router at 192.168.2.1.  Router supplies its own IP address as the DNS server to connected devices and passes queries through to the upstream DNS server as provided by ISP.

Several Apple, Android, Roku, and Windows devices connect and function properly.  Notably, though, one native Linux machine and two Linux virtual machines running different versions of Linux Mint are failing DNS queries.  The two VMs are running on other-wise functioning Windows hosts.  In Windows "ping example.com" works as expected with no delay in name resolution.  In Linux, even on a VM running on the same machine, "ping example.com" has a 15 second delay and fails with "temporary failure in name resolution".

All Linux machines can have resolv.conf edited to point to the upstream DNS servers or public DNS servers and then function properly.  However when they point to the router, DNS queries from only the Linux machines fail.  Windows machines have been verified to be set to the router as the DNS server and all function properly.

Curiously, when resolv.conf points to the router then dig fails when run directly but succeeds when manually pointed to the same router DNS server IP address that resolv.conf it set to:

```
~ $ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 196.168.2.1

~ $ ping example.com
ping: example.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

~ $ dig example.com
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

~ $ dig example.com @192.168.2.1
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> example.com @192.168.2.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 43446
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        72211   IN  A   93.184.216.34

;; Query time: 39 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.2.1#53(192.168.2.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Sep 23 13:35:13 ADT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```

But when resolv.conf points to a public DNS server directly...

```
~ $ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 1.1.1.1

~ $ ping example.com
PING example.com (93.184.216.34) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 93.184.216.34 (93.184.216.34): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=30.0 ms


 $ dig example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 5675
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        82272   IN  A   93.184.216.34

;; Query time: 39 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Sep 23 13:47:49 ADT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56

~ $ dig example.com @192.168.2.1

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> example.com @192.168.2.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 65116
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        82267   IN  A   93.184.216.34

;; Query time: 39 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.2.1#53(192.168.2.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Sep 23 13:47:57 ADT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit strange. I'm order to start narrowing down the problem I would try some of the following -

Run a tcpdump in 1 window while doing DNS queries in another ( A command like "tcpdump -I any port 53" ) and watch for traffic leaving and returning.

Try using did (dig @192.168.2.1 example.com)

For the sake of completeness I would also try

- temporarily disable selinux if its on.
- disabling the firewall or Inserting an iptables rule to allow all traffic on port 53
- Ensuring I only have a single network device active (is Ethernet OR wifi, not both.
- Check if I can otherwise access the router from Linux (web, ICMP)
- Try reboot the router.